# Duplicate database for standby returns error ORA-19625: error identifying file /home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl

Tags: oracle, rman, duplication, standby

I'm working on creating duplication scripts for standby purposes. and it's constantly failing even though the backups are located in the exact same folder.
DB structure is identical and spfile is already configured for standby.
and it results in this.

```
channel aux1: restoring control file
ORA-19625: error identifying file /home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
ORA-19600: input file is control file  (/home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl)
ORA-19601: output file is control file  (/opt/oracle/oradata/vcas/control01.ctl)
failover to previous backup
```

I have been searching a solution for a few days now and I think I need the help of the community. It does work if I take the backup in the flash recovery area, but i need this method because it will be applied on a cluster to cluster replication using ASM on both clusters.
Thank you in advance:

**Details below:**

This is the procedure I'm using:
From my primary server:
I perform the backup.

```
rman target sys/verimatrix@to_primary auxiliary sys/verimatrix@to_standby catalog rman/cat@to_primary << EOF
> RUN {
> allocate channel d1 type disk;
> backup format '/home/oracle/ForStandby_%U.bkp' database;
> sql 'alter system archive log current';
> backup format '/home/oracle/ForStandby_arc_%U.bkp' archivelog all;
> backup current controlfile for standby format '/home/oracle/ForStandbyCTRL.bkp';
> release channel d1;
> }
> EOF
```

Then I copy them to the standby in the oracle home as well:

```
$scp ForStandby* vmx@192.168.1.149:/home/vmx
ForStandby_0qoib29b_1_1.bkp                                  100%  545MB  23.7MB/s   00:23
ForStandby_0roib29i_1_1.bkp                                  100% 6976KB   6.8MB/s   00:00
ForStandby_arc_0soib29n_1_1.bkp                              100%   49MB  24.6MB/s   00:02
ForStandbyCTRL.bkp                                           100% 6944KB   6.8MB/s   00:00
```

On standby server:

```
[oracle@standby ~]$ ll
total 622716
-rw------- 1 oracle dba  571039744 Aug 27 13:51 ForStandby_0qoib29b_1_1.bkp
-rw------- 1 oracle dba    7143424 Aug 27 13:51 ForStandby_0roib29i_1_1.bkp
-rw------- 1 oracle dba   51538432 Aug 27 13:51 ForStandby_arc_0soib29n_1_1.bkp
-rw------- 1 oracle dba    7110656 Aug 27 13:51 ForStandbyCTRL.bkp
```

Then I execute the duplicate command from the primary:

```
[oracle@primary ~]$ rman target sys/verimatrix@to_primary auxiliary sys/verimatrix@to_standby catalog rman/cat@to_primary << EOF

> RUN
> {
>   ALLOCATE CHANNEL C1 type disk;
>   ALLOCATE AUXILIARY CHANNEL aux1 TYPE DISK;
>   DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE FOR STANDBY NOFILENAMECHECK DORECOVER;
>   RELEASE CHANNEL C1;
>   RELEASE CHANNEL aux1;
> }
> EOF
```

Which fails like this invariably:

```
Recovery Manager: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Tue Aug 27 07:59:02 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: VCAS (DBID=3516284596)
connected to recovery catalog database
connected to auxiliary database: VCAS (not mounted)

RMAN> 2> 3> 4> 5> 6>
allocated channel: C1
channel C1: sid=139 devtype=DISK

allocated channel: aux1
channel aux1: sid=152 devtype=DISK

Starting Duplicate Db at 27-AUG-13

contents of Memory Script:
{
   set until scn  429183;
   restore clone standby controlfile;
   sql clone 'alter database mount standby database';
}
executing Memory Script

executing command: SET until clause

Starting restore at 27-AUG-13

channel aux1: restoring control file
ORA-19625: error identifying file /home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
ORA-19600: input file is control file  (/home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl)
ORA-19601: output file is control file  (/opt/oracle/oradata/vcas/control01.ctl)
failover to previous backup
```

Comment: Can you post the control file part of the pfile or string spfile?

Comment: Move `/home/oracle/ForStandbyCTRL.bkp` to `/home/oracle/stdbyctrl.ctl` ?

Comment: Did you check active duplication?
DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE
  FOR STANDBY
  FROM ACTIVE DATABASE
  PASSWORD FILE
  ...

Comment: @Phil, where is he getting this value from. He needs a solution not a quick fix :)

Comment: @Munchi I /think/ it looks for a file called `$ORACLE_HOME/$ORACLE_SID.ctl` (then looks in `$ORACLE_HOME/dbs`), so my suggestion is THE fix, not a quick fix

Comment: I don't think he called his db "stdbyctrl".

Comment: Never got the duplicate command to work.

Comment: I used catalog start with '/home/oracle/ForStandby' then did RMAN>restore database; RMAN>recover database; and finally SQL>recover managed standby database disconnect; That duplicate command is useless. I have to move the files accross anyway....

Comment: Note, I did try to rename my backup hahaha. It didn't work x)

Comment: you're mixing 2 types of "duplication". Decide on one, try it out and let us know where you fail. Stop mixing!